# Too many threads, too much requests, tomcat cannot serve it - architecture design

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, restful-architecture

I need some advice for an architecture re-design.
We have a endpoint, which is called 2-3 millions a day, that's an important endpoint for us, so it needs to be pretty fast.
That endpoint needs some data which is gathered from multiple (slow) services.

We created an other mid-layer service (Spring), which **parallel** calls the slow services to collect the data, the data is cached as well (memcache) and it serves the collected data to our first endpoint. 
Too many services are invoked, which means one request creates at least 5-6 extra threads.

We pre-cache the 10% of the available data (most interested), but we are facing a problem with the rest 90%.

So if the requests are coming for the 90%, the service cannot provide the response in time (no data in cache), and the threads still running till other requests are coming. Some time later the tomcat threads run out of capacity and the new requests cannot be served.

We cannot cache the rest 90%, because that would affect the size of the cache and the pricing.
The best approach would be that serving data only for the 10%, but that's not the requirement...
What do you think how can we re-design to concept to solve the huge load?

Comment: DOS'ing yourself is always a bad thing to happen. One possible answer to this (assuming you're also in control of the clients) would be to breakdown the responsibilities of the service. At the moment you have a single god like service (the mid layer) that acts as the main entry point for requests. You can try to breakdown the responsibility of that into smaller services which the client would then invoke to retrieve their data. Thus you have smaller (and assuming) faster services performing you job.

Comment: Also slowness in data retrieval could happen by needed db access to retrieve them. Thus I would check that area as well for any improvements.

Comment: A few points, I would a) create a pool of threads you know the system can handle and not create more dynamically b) if you can't service a request you should reject it to minimise overhead c) if you are getting requests for data you are not caching perhaps more data is interesting after all. i.e. you are not caching enough.

Comment: In addition to what  Peter Lawrey suggested, run your  mid-layer service on several machines, and balance load between them with ngnix.

Comment: If you can't provide a response to the 90% of the requests where the answers aren't in the cache, why are you bothering to run threads for them?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I try to response to all of them:

Comment: 1.  The service cannot be breakdown into multiple services that's the requirement.
2. Changing memcache to db is a possible way, I will investigate that possibility.

Comment: 3. Creating a thread pool would be fine. Caching more data would be the best, but that's time and resource consuming.
4. The service is in a cloud provider behind a load balancer.
5. Initially the service should respond for the 90% as well, but it turned out that the downstream services are pretty slow, but yes you are right, maybe a restriction would be fine for handling the requests.